# D3...get a circle to appear on mouseover and dissapear on mouseout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a line chart. When the user mouses over a point on that line, I'd like to display a circle (see [this](http://nvd3.com/ghpages/linePlusBar.html))

I am not using nvd3, but just d3. I have:

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.number); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.people); })
      .style("fill", "white").style("stroke","black")
      .style("display", "none")
      .on('mouseover', function() {
        d3.select(this).style("display","inline");
  })
      .on('mouseout', function() {
        d3.select(this).style("display", "none");
      });
```

I initially set the display of the circle to "none", and then to visible when the user hovers over it with their mouse. I then hide it again when they mouseout. However, the circle isn't appearing when I mouseover. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the circle is set to display none, there is nothing there to catch the event in the first place. Try to use another element as the trigger for the circle.

Comment: I tried display:hidden as suggested and even visibility:hidden but neither of them worked.

Comment: Indeed, display hidden is incorrect and visibility hidden was what I was thinking of. Sorry for the misinformation. How about setting the fill / stroke to transparent?

Comment: Also, radius 1 is very small, you might miss it!